# Keep original canvas aspect ratio when resize browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, aspect-ratio

I have canvas with width: 100%; and height: 100%. It is fullscreen and I draw an image on it. I would like keep original aspect ratio of the image when I resize my browser. I would like the same effect as if I would do this: http://pastebin.com/pFEQJsvM . Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Here is my javscript code:
http://pastebin.com/U5VpzfbZ

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Bespin (back when it existed) did something very similar.

Put it in a div. Make the Div 100%/100%. You can use an onresize event or timer to check if the div's client size has changed. If it has, resize the canvas to be the same size as the div.